# How to move the table to next page in word document using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, office-addins

I have a word template . It has two tables consist of xml nodes. In few situations i have to  move second   table to second page in same word document. 
Does anyone know how to move the table to next page.

i know only moving row ....

```
  Table tbl = aDoc.Tables[1];
    Row toMove = tbl.Rows[src];
    object beforeRow = tbl.Rows[dest];
    Row newRow = tbl.Rows.Add(ref beforeRow);
    toMove.Select();
    wrd.Selection.Copy();
    newRow.Select();
    wrd.Selection.Paste();
    toMove.Delete();
    newRow.Delete();
```

But i don't know how to move the table to next page in same document.....

Answer (score 0):

To select next page range:

```
 Set TopOfNextPage = rng.Duplicate.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext)
```

and to scroll to that range:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220751(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Can you explain how to move table to next page.....i did not understand next page range....

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a template you can insert bookmarks into the template and then use range to jump around through the document using the bookmark range. 
Open your template in Word and add a bookmark. In Word2010 go to 'Insert->Bookmark' add a bookmark name e.g 'firstTable' somewhere. Then in C# code:

```
object pageBookmark = "firstTable";
Range range = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref pageBookmark).Range;  
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table myTable = doc.Tables.Add(range, 5, 5);//enter what size you want ur table.
```

This will allow you to insert the table in the section you want no matter how big your first table is.